# StencilJs/Jsx: render HTMLElements in nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, stenciljs

This is my component:

```
@Component({
  tag: "my-alert-list",
  styleUrl: "alert-list.scss",
  shadow: true,
})
export class AlertList {
  @State() alertList: object[] = [];

  @Method()
  async appendAlert(
    type: string,
    message: string,
    htmlContent: object,
    canClose: boolean = false,
    closeDelay: number
  ) {
    let alertBoxElement = (
      <my-alert-box
        alert-type={type}
        message={message}
        can-close={canClose}
        close-delay={closeDelay}
        opened
      >
      {htmlContent}
      </my-alert-box>
    );
    this.alertList = [
      ...this.alertList,
      alertBoxElement
    ]
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        {this.alertList}
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

The method `appendAlert` aims to append a new `my-alert-box` element to the list of alerts.
In same case i don't want to pass a simple text to the `my-alert-box` but some HTML block.
(`my-alert-box` has a receiver slot element and i verified that it works).
I tried to achieve this with the htmlContent variable as you can see, but of course it doesn't work if i do:

```
$('#alertlist')[0].appendAlert(type='info',message='', htmlContent=document.createElement('div'))
```

I receive the error:

> [STENCIL-DEV-MODE] vNode passed as children has unexpected type.
>   Make sure it's using the correct h() function.
>   Empty objects can also be the cause, look for JSX comments that became objects.

Any idea on how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible like this because JSX works differently. You could pass the `htmlContent` as a string and use `innerHTML` on `my-alert-box` but it's dangerous (XSS).

Ionic's `ion-alert` has the same limitation with the `message` prop... see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#properties which has a link to https://ionicframework.com/docs/techniques/security, and there they explain how they do some basic DOM sanitization (`@ionic/core` is also built with Stencil).